# How can i download a file from a website using script?

Tags: shell

I am very new to scripting and i am not sure which script will be helping me out.

I need to download a file from a website and also it should happen as recurring download every morning.

could someone kindly suggest me a script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you running the script under? If it's linux try 'man wget'.

Comment: I am planning to run in Linux OS. Can you give me an example of script template tat i can follow?

Answer (score 2):

You should use either [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), one or both of them are part of many Linux distributions, there are also Windows and OSX versions available.

To make the script run on a regular basis you will need to use the [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) scheduler on Linux/UNIX/OSX, WIndows has its own [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)